# SNMP Subagent Development

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, snmp

I am a newbie to Net-SNMP, I want to implement a Subagent using Net-SNMP on windows which will provide the information about my server statistics like calls processed, calls failed etc.
I did the Net-SNMP installation as provided by 
http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=26151
and trying to compile the example given on the Net-SNMP
http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent

I have created a new project under VS2005 and have used the code from the above URL and have provided the include and the lib path and have provided the desired libraries.

While compiling I am getting following linking errors, please help me to get rid of these errors.

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>SNMPFirst.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _snmp_enable_calllog referenced in function _wmain
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(master_admin.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(subagent.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(agentx_config.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(protocol.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(master.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(vacm_conf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(iquery.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(usmConf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(cache_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(stash_to_next.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(table_data.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(table.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(stash_cache.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(table_dataset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(debug_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(null.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(watcher.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(serialize.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(read_only.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(instance.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(all_helpers.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(bulk_to_next.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmphelpers.lib(old_api.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(agent_trap.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(agent_sysORTable.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(agent_read_config.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(agent_index.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(snmp_agent.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(snmp_vars.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(agent_handler.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(agent_registry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __forceCRTManifestCUR
1>netsnmpagent.lib(snmp_agent.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _select@20 referenced in function _agent_check_and_process
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(protocol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ntohl@4 referenced in function _agentx_realloc_build_int
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(protocol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ntohs@4 referenced in function _agentx_realloc_build_short
1>netsnmpmibs.lib(protocol.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _htonl@4 referenced in function _agentx_realloc_build_double
1>D:\Kirusa\working\SNMPFirst\Debug\SNMPFirst.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361682/vc9-sp1-generates-manifests-with-the-wrong-version-number

Comment: Thanks for the URL, that gave me hint, I was using latest version of Net-SNMP which is compiled with VC 9.0 while I was using VC 8.0. Using this URL I could have made it working with 9.0 binaries but I preferred to download the older version of Net-SNMP which is compiled with VC8.0

Comment: Then you can add your own detailed answer and accept your own answer. This is OK too. :-)

Comment: And the url still works, must be a record for a Microsoft url. Then again, it's not an MSDN url. :-)